# Why are my ally's powers greyed out?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Sometimes my squadmates (especially EDI and James) have their powers greyed out, but usable. I can cast them from the menu just fine, but they're grey instead of the shade of blue they usually are when they're filled out.

What does this mean? I assume it has something to do with the power-slowing skills these characters have? Does using these powers cancel Fortification/ect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is just a bug in the game's GUI, and doesn't affect gameplay.

I have encountered the same thing under random circumstances, so I'm going to guess that this is just a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't noticed any gameplay effects, I was thinking it's related to Fortification/EDI's shield though, I only notice it on Her and James

Comment: @BenBrocka In that case, it could be the game forgetting to highlight the powers again after the cooldown, because those abilities have such long cooldown times. Just a theory.